# Best practices to use aws cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am using aws cognito to register and authentication of users, but I have a problem. I need administrate this users and I not know if it is good use aws cognito like BD or create other BD (in elasticsearch or any other) with all attributes of this users. This way I will have the data on two platform. What is the best in my case?

Comment: What is a "BD"?

Comment: Sorry, Data Base (DB), in spanish is "Base de Datos" (BD).

Answer (score 1):

It entirely depends on your use case. Cognito user pool table is enough if all you are looking to do is store and access user data for the users when they need it. If you want rapid access to all user data to perform certain operations in the backend, you can store the user reference on dynamodb with username as the primary key.